# Amazon Cognito "RespondToAuthChallenge" - returns a NotAuthorizedException, Incorrect username or password

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-js, aws-userpools

In cognito user pools I have two different groups: Admin & User. I want to allow admin users to create cognito user, so I created new user with AdminCreateUser method of CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.
Ref Link - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/how-to-create-user-accounts.html

Now I want to authorize the user in userpool. I am following this link - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-authentication-flow.html - Client-Side Authentication Flow.
But “RespondToAuthChallenge” - returns a NotAuthorizedException, Incorrect username or password.

```
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk'
import { SRPClient, calculateSignature, getNowString } from 'amazon-user-pool-srp-client'


const userPoolId = 'XXX'
const ClientId = 'XXX'

const verifyUser = () => {
    AWS.config.region = 'us-west-2'
    const srp = new SRPClient(userPoolId)
    const SRP_A = srp.calculateA()
    var params = {
      AuthFlow: 'USER_SRP_AUTH',
      ClientId,
      AuthParameters: {
        USERNAME: formState.email,
        SRP_A,
      },
    }
    let cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider()
    cognitoidentityserviceprovider.initiateAuth(params, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        const error = err.message ? err.message : err
        console.log(error)
      }
      else {
        console.log(data) // --> data.session is undefined
        if (data.ChallengeParameters && data.ChallengeName) {
          const passwordAuthenticationKey =
            srp.getPasswordAuthenticationKey(
              data.ChallengeParameters.USER_ID_FOR_SRP,
              formState.password,
              data.ChallengeParameters.SRP_B,
              data.ChallengeParameters.SALT
            )
          const dateNow = getNowString()
          const signatureString = calculateSignature(
            passwordAuthenticationKey,
            userPoolId,
            data.ChallengeParameters.USER_ID_FOR_SRP,
            data.ChallengeParameters.SECRET_BLOCK, dateNow
          )

          var params = {
            ChallengeName: data.ChallengeName,
            ClientId,
            ChallengeResponses: {
              // PASSWORD_VERIFIER
              PASSWORD_CLAIM_SIGNATURE: signatureString,
              PASSWORD_CLAIM_SECRET_BLOCK: data.ChallengeParameters.SECRET_BLOCK,
              TIMESTAMP: dateNow,
              USERNAME: data.ChallengeParameters.USER_ID_FOR_SRP,
            },
            Session: data.Session, // undefined
          };
          cognitoidentityserviceprovider.respondToAuthChallenge(params, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
              const error = err.message ? err.message : err
              console.log(error) // Incorrect username or password
            }
            else {
              console.log(data)
            }
          })
        }
      }
    })
  }
```

I created diff users, but no luck. User gets registered but respondToAuthChallenge throws error.
InitiateAuth response returns challengeName and challengeParameters but session is not provided.

I found this statement which I am not able to comprehend -
"When the next operation of RespondToAuthChallenge proof of password runs, Amazon Cognito returns a generic NotAuthorizedException error indicating either user name or password was incorrect." in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pool-managing-errors.html

Kindly let me know if you have any solution/idea, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the Session field is not a required field based on the [RespondToAuthChallenge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_RespondToAuthChallenge.html#CognitoUserPools-RespondToAuthChallenge-request-Session) documentation so you might not even need to pass it for PASSWORD_VERIFIER challenge if its not provided.

secondly, Can you include the complete error message and the responses you are getting from both the initiateAuth and the respondToAuthChallenge operations so I can take a look?

Also bear in mind that the session field in the response from initiateAuth operation is "Session" with uppercase "S" (here is the doc for  [initiateAuth operation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_InitiateAuth.html)) so instead of data.session you have to fetch the session value with data.Session instead.

Comment: Hi @Sina, could you please also look at this - 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68388290/cognito-php-password-verifier-challenge-returns-incorrect-username-and-password
I am facing a similar issue here and unable to figure out the root cause of it.